# F# provide downcast type as function argument

Tags: f#

I am doing some interfacing with some C# libraries and need to do some casting of objects.  There is some duplication of code that I think could be solved by being able to pass the type of the downcast as an argument.

```
// transform exceptions into Option type
let tryFn fn =
    try Some(fn()) with ex -> None

let tryCastString (o: obj) = tryFn (fun () -> o :?> string)
let tryCastUInt64 (o: obj) = tryFn (fun () -> o :?> uint64)

// I would like to do something like the following
let tryCast (o: obj) (t: type) = tryFn (fun () -> o :?> t)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a type argument:

```
let tryCast<'R> (o: obj) = tryFn (fun () -> o :?> 'R)
```

This has the additional advantage that type inference can get that type inferred for you in many cases, here's a simple example:

```
let x: int64 option = tryCast "4"
```

Here you don't need to specify the type, because it is known to the compiler that `x` is of type `option<int64>`.